# MYSQL where x in all

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query like this

```
SELECT .......  WHERE column_name IN (1,2,3)
```

How can I use the same query and say

```
SELECT ........WHERE column_name IN (*)
```

and select all rows?

**Edit:** The reason I need to do this is because of a bad database design and bad coding in general, for now I need to hack it. If I don't pass the query 1,2,3 .. I need to pass it something so it will return me all records. Is there a way to do it without changing the query? If you don't think this is possible then you should say that it is not possible in your answer.

Comment: Just omit the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: WHERE column_name NOT IN (-1) , if you know that values cannot be less than 0 and you still need WHERE clause

Comment: are `(1,2,3)` constants or the result of a query?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `WHERE` clause alltogether.

Comment: can't do that, using only one query and passing it 1,2,3,4... or if 0 i want all

Comment: What *can* you change? Only the parameter?

Comment: Have you evaluated TZHX's answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must have the WHERE clause, you could say:

```
WHERE 1
```

Or if you need to do the column_name IN bit, you could do something like:

```
SELECT .......  WHERE column_name IN (1,2,3) OR 1
```

Comment: +1 as this would have been my answer if OP can't remove the where clause but can add something to it. Depending on how it would be added, OP should be very wary of SQL Injection though.

Answer (score 1):

`... IN (SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table) ...`

Comment: Not a good technique but it appears my friend that you have answered the question

Comment: Technique sucks :) but like you said I just wanted to provide an answer to the exact question. I've never had to SQL-Inject my own code...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter your return table base on values in another table:

select column_1, column_2
from table_1
where column_1 IN (select column_with_value from tabl_2)